# How does immunotherapy for allergies work in dogs?

Tags: dogs, medicines, allergies

I recently got my dog allergy tested in an effort to determine what makes her so itchy all the time. It turns out she's allergic to nearly everything (41 out 55 tested allergens, with many being severe).

The next step in the process is to begin an immunotherapy treatment, which involves (in her case) getting a daily injection of two different types of a specially made vaccine (alternated each day between "vial A" and "vial B) for 30 days, where each day we up the dosage until a certain point where it's then backed down.  At that point, the injection is still alternated between vials and only given every "X" day, depending on when this part of the process begins (i.e. vial A on Mondays, vial B on Thursdays).

What should I expect to see in my dog? When should I see relief in the itchiness of my dog?

Comment: This is not meant to be a sassy comment. But these are questions you should ask your vet. They prescribed the treatment, they will know best how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Each allergy shot has a very small amount of the allergen that triggers a reaction in your pupper. The therapy is designed to "present" the allergen to his body, under the threshold that triggers a reaction, so that, when in the future his body detects the allergen in the real world he doesn't react (as bad).

Comment: Post looks like a good answer, but is a bit short and could benefit from support of some external references, could you please consider adding some more information, thanks.